GEE: Error generating timeseries chart: User memory limit exceeded
I would like to plot a timeseries for MSAVi and NDVI for two different areas of interest. It works for one of the areas but not for the second area. I tried to adjust the pixel size and the time range but still received the error "User memory limit exceeded". Is this error just caused because the second area is larger than the first one? How could I solve this?
Link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d0502355efc57ef975f8f2edb2d652f
//Calculate NDVI from terraSR and terraSR8d
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b01']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
 
// Calculate MSAVI from terraSR and terraSR8d
var MSAVI = '(2 * b("sur_refl_b02") + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * b("sur_refl_b02") + 1), 2) - 8 * (b("sur_refl_b02") - b("sur_refl_b01"))) ) / 2';

var addMSAVI = function(image){
  return image.addBands(image.multiply(0.0001).expression(MSAVI).rename("MSAVI"));
};

// identify pixels with clouds via the bitmask to produce a quality mask
// for bit information, refer to https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MOD09GA
// quality mask is also used for the analysing the single sites

var bitwiseExtract = function(input, fromBit, toBit) {
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit);
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1);
  return input.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask);
};

var QualityMask = function(img) {
  var imgMask = bitwiseExtract(img.select("state_1km"), 0, 1).eq(0); //Bits 0-1 from the bitmask are chosen and only pixels where bit is 0 (=clear) shall be used, all other pixels are masked/removed
  var imgQ = img.updateMask(imgMask); 
  return imgQ;
};

//Cloud mask for terraSR8d
var QualityMask8d = function(img) {
  var imgMask = bitwiseExtract(img.select("QA"), 0, 1).eq(0); //Bits 0-1 from the bitmask are chosen and only pixels where bit is 0 (=clear) shall be used, all other pixels are masked/removed
  var imgQ = img.updateMask(imgMask);
  return imgQ;
};

//----- Richtersveld

var terraSR0012_Richtersveld = terraSR.filterBounds(Richtersveld).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2012-01-01').map(QualityMask).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);
var terraSR1224_Richtersveld = terraSR.filterBounds(Richtersveld).filterDate('2012-01-01', '2024-10-01').map(QualityMask).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);

var terraSR0012_Richtersveld = terraSR0012_Richtersveld.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var terraSR1224_Richtersveld = terraSR1224_Richtersveld.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var Timeseriesdaily0012_Richtersveld = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR0012_Richtersveld.select("MSAVI", "NDVI"), Richtersveld, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat");
var Timeseriesdaily1224_Richtersveld = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR1224_Richtersveld.select("MSAVI", "NDVI"), Richtersveld, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat");

print(Timeseriesdaily0012_Richtersveld);
print(Timeseriesdaily1224_Richtersveld);

// from terraSR8d
var terraSR8d0024_Richtersveld = terraSR8d.filterBounds(Richtersveld).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2024-10-01').map(QualityMask8d).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);

var terraSR8d0024_Richtersveld = terraSR8d0024_Richtersveld.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var Timeseries8d0024_Richtersveld_chart = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR8d0024_Richtersveld.select("MSAVI", "NDVI"), Richtersveld, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat")
  .setOptions({
   title: 'MSAVI & NDVI timeseries for Richtersveld (from MODIS 8d)',
   trendlines: {
     0: {color: 'CC0000'}
   },
   lineWidth: 1,
   pointSize: 3,
  });
print(Timeseries8d0024_Richtersveld_chart);

//----- Knersvlakte
var terraSR0012 = terraSR.filterBounds(Knersvlakte).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2012-01-01').map(QualityMask).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI)

var terraSR0012_Knersvlakte = terraSR.filterBounds(Knersvlakte).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2012-01-01').map(QualityMask).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);
var terraSR1224_Knersvlakte = terraSR.filterBounds(Knersvlakte).filterDate('2012-01-01', '2024-10-01').map(QualityMask).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);

var terraSR0012_Knersvlakte = terraSR0012_Knersvlakte.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var terraSR1224_Knersvlakte = terraSR1224_Knersvlakte.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var Timeseriesdaily0012_Knersvlakte = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR0012_Knersvlakte.select("MSAVI", "NDVI"), Knersvlakte, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat");
var Timeseriesdaily1224_Knersvlakte = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR1224_Knersvlakte.select("MSAVI", "NDVI"), Knersvlakte, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat");

print(Timeseriesdaily0012_Knersvlakte);
print(Timeseriesdaily1224_Knersvlakte);

// from terraSR8d
var terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte = terraSR8d.filterBounds(Knersvlakte).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2024-10-01').map(QualityMask8d).map(addMSAVI).map(addNDVI);
var terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte_bands = terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte.select("MSAVI");


var terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte_bands = terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte_bands.map(function(image) {
  return ee.Image(image).set('timeFormat', image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

var Timeseries8d0024_Knersvlakte_chart = ui.Chart.image.series(terraSR8d0024_Knersvlakte_bands, Knersvlakte, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, "timeFormat")
  .setOptions({
   title: 'MSAVI & NDVI timeseries for Knersvlakte (from MODIS 8d)',
   trendlines: {
     0: {color: 'CC0000'}
   },
   lineWidth: 1,
   pointSize: 3,
  });
print(Timeseries8d0024_Knersvlakte_chart);


I reduced the periods in time to 5-years intervals, which solved the problem but is not the most elegant way.
